# Cannot automount any usb external device under quantal

Tags: upgrade, 12.10, usb, updates, automount

I recently upgrade to quantal and I have to mount all my devices (usb key, extrernal hard drive and even data cd) manually.

I get the following error message in a pop-up window when I insert any eternal media:

```
Adding read ACL for uid 1322 to `/media/iovleff' failed: Operation not supported
```

By the way, my user name is "iovleff" and my uid is 1322.

Can you help me in some way?